# Optimisation algorithm, constraints and score calculation configurations with Optapy

Tags: python, optaplanner, optapy

I am using the Optapy library in python, and I am using the school timetabling instance on GitHub as a base. I have few questions regarding the library configurations:

- How do I choose the optimisation algorithm (e.g. tabu search or
  simulated annealing)?
- How do Optapy calculate the score of a solution? Do I have the option
  to change the score calculation type in python?
- How can I decide the weights for each constraint, except hard or soft
  constraint?

I was looking at OptaPlanner User Guide, but I am not sure how to implement it on python.

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OptaPy can be configured using the programmatic API. The config classes can be found in the `optapy.config` package. In particular, you choose the optimisation algorithm via `withPhases`:

```
import optapy.config
solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig().withEntityClasses(get_class(Lesson)) \
    .withSolutionClass(get_class(TimeTable)) \
    .withConstraintProviderClass(get_class(define_constraints)) \
    .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(30)) \
    .withPhases([
        optapy.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig(),
        optapy.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig()
            .withAcceptorConfig(optapy.config.localsearch.decider.acceptor.LocalSearchAcceptorConfig()
                                .withSimulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature("0hard/0soft"))
    ])
```

(the above configures simulated annealing).

Recently added was the `@easy_score_calculator` and `@incremental_score_calculator` decorators, which allows you to define an EasyScoreCalculator or IncrementalScoreCalculator respectively. For example, (EasyScoreCalculator, maximize value):

```
@optapy.easy_score_calculator
def my_score_calculator(solution: Solution):
    total_score = 0
    for entity in solution.entity_list:
        total_score += 0 if entity.value is None else entity.value
    return optapy.score.SimpleScore.of(total_score)

solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig()
termination_config = optapy.config.solver.termination.TerminationConfig()
termination_config.setBestScoreLimit('9')
solver_config.withSolutionClass(optapy.get_class(Solution)) \
    .withEntityClasses(optapy.get_class(Entity)) \
    .withEasyScoreCalculatorClass(optapy.get_class(my_score_calculator)) \
    .withTerminationConfig(termination_config)
```

or with an IncrementalScoreCalculator (NQueens):

```
@optapy.incremental_score_calculator
class IncrementalScoreCalculator:
    score: int
    row_index_map: dict
    ascending_diagonal_index_map: dict
    descending_diagonal_index_map: dict

    def resetWorkingSolution(self, working_solution: Solution):
        n = working_solution.n
        self.row_index_map = dict()
        self.ascending_diagonal_index_map = dict()
        self.descending_diagonal_index_map = dict()
        for i in range(n):
            self.row_index_map[i] = list()
            self.ascending_diagonal_index_map[i] = list()
            self.descending_diagonal_index_map[i] = list()
            if i != 0:
                self.ascending_diagonal_index_map[n - 1 + i] = list()
                self.descending_diagonal_index_map[-i] = list()
        self.score = 0
        for queen in working_solution.queen_list:
            self.insert(queen)

    def beforeEntityAdded(self, entity: any):
        pass

    def afterEntityAdded(self, entity: any):
        self.insert(entity)

    def beforeVariableChanged(self, entity: any, variableName: str):
        self.retract(entity)

    def afterVariableChanged(self, entity: any, variableName: str):
        self.insert(entity)

    def beforeEntityRemoved(self, entity: any):
        self.retract(entity)

    def afterEntityRemoved(self, entity: any):
        pass

    def insert(self, queen: Queen):
        row = queen.row
        if row is not None:
            row_index = queen.row
            row_index_list = self.row_index_map[row_index]
            self.score -= len(row_index_list)
            row_index_list.append(queen)
            ascending_diagonal_index_list = self.ascending_diagonal_index_map[queen.getAscendingDiagonalIndex()]
            self.score -= len(ascending_diagonal_index_list)
            ascending_diagonal_index_list.append(queen)
            descending_diagonal_index_list = self.descending_diagonal_index_map[queen.getDescendingDiagonalIndex()]
            self.score -= len(descending_diagonal_index_list)
            descending_diagonal_index_list.append(queen)

    def retract(self, queen: Queen):
        row = queen.row
        if row is not None:
            row_index = queen.row
            row_index_list = self.row_index_map[row_index]
            row_index_list.remove(queen)
            self.score += len(row_index_list)
            ascending_diagonal_index_list = self.ascending_diagonal_index_map[queen.getAscendingDiagonalIndex()]
            ascending_diagonal_index_list.remove(queen)
            self.score += len(ascending_diagonal_index_list)
            descending_diagonal_index_list = self.descending_diagonal_index_map[queen.getDescendingDiagonalIndex()]
            descending_diagonal_index_list.remove(queen)
            self.score += len(descending_diagonal_index_list)

    def calculateScore(self) -> optapy.score.SimpleScore:
        return optapy.score.SimpleScore.of(self.score)

solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig()
termination_config = optapy.config.solver.termination.TerminationConfig()
termination_config.setBestScoreLimit('0')
solver_config.withSolutionClass(optapy.get_class(Solution)) \
    .withEntityClasses(optapy.get_class(Queen)) \
    .withScoreDirectorFactory(optapy.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig() \
                              .withIncrementalScoreCalculatorClass(optapy.get_class(IncrementalScoreCalculator))) \
    .withTerminationConfig(termination_config)
```

If by weights you mean `ConstraintConfiguration` (which allows you to define custom constraint weights per problem), that is not exposed via OptaPy yet. If you mean how to make a constraint weight more/less, either change the second parameter to `penalize/reward` (if constant), or add a third parameter that computes the constraint multiplier (which the second parameter will be multiplied by), like so:

```
def undesired_day_for_employee(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return constraint_factory.forEach(shift_class) \
        .join(availability_class, [Joiners.equal(lambda shift: shift.employee,
                                                 lambda availability: availability.employee),
                                   Joiners.equal(lambda shift: shift.start.date(),
                                                 lambda availability: availability.date)
                                   ]) \
        .filter(lambda shift, availability: availability.availability_type == AvailabilityType.UNDESIRED) \
        .penalize('Undesired day for employee', HardSoftScore.ofSoft(2),
                  lambda shift, availability: get_shift_duration_in_minutes(shift))
```

(this constraint penalizes by 2 soft for every minute an employee works on an UNDESIRED day)

Comment: I could change the optimisation algorithm now with your code. What is the default of the optimisation algorithm if I do not define the specific optimisation algorithm in Optapy? Are all the algorithms described in Optaplanner guide usable in Optapy?
In addition, is there any quick option to export the output to .csv or another format?

Comment: The default optimization algorithm in OptaPy would be the same as the default optimization algorithm in OptaPlanner, which is a Construction Heuristic (First Fit) followed by a Local Search Phase (Late Acceptance with size 400). All the algorithms described in the OptaPlanner guide should be usable in OptaPy, but a few might not be usable if they require strength comparator classes (ex: FIRST_FIT_DECREASING) (since there no decorator yet to create the comparator class from a function; once such a decorator is added, then they should be usable my passing the decorated function in the config).